# Git go back N commits locally, run tests, and fix OR go back to original tip

Tags: git

Say I have a local branch that I haven't made public yet with:

```
A -> B -> C [HEAD of my branch]
```

I would like to go back a number of commits (e.g. to `A`) run some tests, and depending on the result do either one of these:

1. Make fixes on a new commit and have HEAD point to the new fix

   ```
   A -> Fix [HEAD of my branch]
     \
      B -> C
   ```
2. Don't do anything and just go back to the original tip, i.e.

   ```
   A-> B -> C [HEAD of my branch]
   ```

How can I do `1` and `2`?

Comment: Are commits B and C supposed to be reachable in case 1? Is some branch reference supposed to point to commit C?

Comment: Thanks @Jubobs not sure what you mean by reachable. They are not associated with any tags, branches or identifiers, other than being a few commits back in the history.

Comment: What I mean is: in case 1, are you happy to just see commits B and C disappear from your history? Or are you interested in retaining them in the history?

Comment: @Jubobs Great point. I am interested in solutions to **both cases**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(In the following, I'm assuming the local branch you're referring to is called `master`.)

At the beginning, your (recent) history looks as follows:

```
A -- B -- C [master, HEAD]
```

Or, equivalently (this representation makes the rest easier to follow):

```
 A
  \
   B -- C [master, HEAD]
```

Before anything else, run `git log --oneline` and identify the commit ID of A; write down a truncated version of it.

There is no reason why you should be in detached HEAD state at any stage, here. Git branches are cheap; use them, and then throw them away if you no longer need them.

So here, create a branch called `temp`, say, that points to commit A and check it out in one fell swoop:

```
git checkout -b temp <commit-id-of-A>
```

You now have

```
 A [temp, HEAD]
  \
   B -- C [master]
```

Run your tests. Then, depending on the results, follow the instructions for either case 1 or case 2.

#### Case 1:

Stage your changes and create a new commit on `temp`. You should now have

```
 A -- Fix [temp, HEAD]
  \
   B -- C [master]
```

At this stage,

- if you wish to **retain commits B and C in your history**, you need to keep some reference that points to commit C; otherwise, they'll just get garbage-collected (after a while) if you don't do anything to rescue them from repository limbo. The simplest thing here is to rename your `master` branch to something else, for instance "backup_C":

  ```
  git branch -m master backup_C
  ```

  You now have

  ```
  A -- Fix [temp, HEAD]
   \
    B -- C [backup_C]
  ```

  Rename your `temp` branch to "master":

  ```
  git branch -m temp master
  ```

  And you're left with

  ```
  A -- Fix [master, HEAD]
   \
    B -- C [backup_C]
  ```
- otherwise, simply delete `master`.

  ```
  git branch -d master
  ```

  You now have

  ```
  A -- Fix [temp, HEAD]
  ```

  Rename your `temp` branch to "master".

  ```
  git branch -m temp master
  ```

  And you're left with

  ```
  A -- Fix [master, HEAD]
  ```

#### Case 2:

Check out `master` again and delete the `temp` branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d temp
```

And you're back to the original state of your repository:

```
A -- B -- C [master, HEAD]
```

Answer (score 4):

To go back N steps from your head

```
git checkout HEAD~N (where N is an integer)
```

- Make your changes
- Commit your changes
- Copy the hash of that commit. (Let's say it's 1f65c77)

Go back to your former HEAD (let's say you were on master)

`git checkout master`

From here you can

a) Do nothing (your second question)

b) Point your head to the commit you just did (your first question)

`git reset 1f65c77`

- Commit again if there are staged changes.

The 1f65c77 commit is made on a detached branch, so if you decide not to point your HEAD to it, no harm is done.

Comment: Branches are cheap in Git. Why not use a new branch (to be deleted) instead of being in detached HEAD state?

Comment: no special reason. I work that way to keep the gitflow branching scheme clean, but it's just one of the several ways to do this. You could also  do this all with rebase. That's the magic of GIT

Answer (score 2):

There's almost certainly more than one way to do this. Assuming you use actual commit SHAs (or short SHAs) instead of A, B, C, etc.:

First check out the commit A:

```
git checkout A
```

Now you have a choice of doing something or not. Case 2, doing nothing, is easier: the `HEAD` of your branch is still associated with commit C, so you can go back to it by just using

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

or even

```
git checkout HEAD
```

If you've made changes, what you'll need to do is set the `HEAD` of your branch back to commit A, then commit your new changes. [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) should do this for you.

```
git reset --soft A
```

This points the HEAD of your branch to A and preserves your changes-to-be-committed. (You may want to check the linked documentation to make sure `--soft` is the correct mode.) Now you can stage and commit changes, and the commit – which will be the new branch `HEAD` – will have A as its parent rather than C.

There may also be a way to do this with [`git-rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) as well; [this awesome tutorial](https://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/) would show you how, if there is.

Answer (score 0):

Swaping branches would be the only thing that comes to mind i.e.

- `git checkout A`
- run tests

  - case 1:

    - make changes
    - `git branch temp`
    - `git commit -a`
    - `git branch -m my_old_branch temp2`
    - `git branch -m temp my_old_branch`
  - case 2:

    - `git checkout my_old_branch`

result will be

```
A -> Fix [HEAD of my branch]
  \
   B -> C [temp2]
```